# Show package.json version on NuxtJS application

Tags: version, package.json, nuxtjs

I want to use the version number that is configured on `package.json` into my components on NuxtJS application.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At the top of your `nuxt.config.js` file put an import

```
import pkg from './package.json'
```

then, inside the same file, insert this part

```
export default {
  ...
  // https://nuxtjs.org/guide/runtime-config
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    clientVersion: pkg.version,
  }
}
```

Now you can use the variable, inside your components with `$config.clientVersion`

For more details, see the docs at https://nuxtjs.org/guide/runtime-config

Comment: Somehow this seems like a bad idea...